# can we decompose $\mathcal{A}$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$as an orthogonal transformation and a dilation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem**
Any linear transformation of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is the composition of an orthogonal transformation and a dilation along perpendicular directions(with distinct coefficients)

---

for any linear transformation $\mathcal{A}$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$, assume its correspond matrix is $A$,it can be decomposed as below $$A=UDW$$,where $U,W$ is unitary matrices, $D$ is diagonal matrix. So any linear transformation $\mathcal{A}$ is the composition of an orthogonal transformation($W$) and a dilation($D$) along perpendicular directions and an orthogonal transformation($U$). But I don't know how to decompose $\mathcal{A}$ as an orthogonal transformation and a dilation along perpendicular. Please Help me. thanks.

Comment: Isn't that it just in a chosen basis? Could also consider polar decomposition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: Can you decompose $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right]$ in that way?

Comment: @PavelJiranek. Under the basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$,where $e_k=(0,0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)$. the polar decomposition say any matrix is the composition of a Symmetric(or Hermitian) matrix and a unitary matrix..unitary matrix correspond to a orthogonal transformation, but symmetric matrix dose not correspond to a dilation along perpendicular directions.

Comment: First, the symmetric factor in the polar decomposition is positive definite. If a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal is dilation along orthogonal directions $e_i$, why not an SPD matrix? (Just in another orthogonal basis)

Comment: Or positive semi definite to be more precise

Comment: @PavelJiranek I have understood. thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing matrices with linear transformations. It is not always possible to write $A$ in the form of $UD$ or $DU$ with diagonal $D$ and real orthogonal $U$. However, with the decomposition $A=UDW$, we have $U^TAU=D(WU)$. In other words, under a change of basis, the linear transformation $\mathcal{A}$ is the composition of an orthogonal transformation (represented by the matrix $WU$ in the *new* basis) and a dilation (represented by the matrix $D$ in the new basis).